# Recursive function that prints all integers from N to 1 and then from 1 to N

Tags: c, recursion

I just wanted to ask how i can display all integers from N to 1 and again to N with step -+2 and a recursive function, considering that N is given by user. For example, if the user gives 7, then calling the function would print <<7 5 3 1 3 5 7>> or if the parameter is 8, it would print <<8 6 4 2 4 6 8>> I have only figured out to display N to 1 (or N to 2). Here's my code:

```
    int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("Give a:");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    func(a);
    return 0;
}

int func(int n)
{
    printf("\t%d",n);
    if (n==1 || n==2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return func(n-2);
}
```

Comment: hint: paste code, select, ctrl+k. Don't backtick all the lines.

Comment: Another hint: Try printing both before and after the recursive call and see what you get.

Comment: You probably don't need the function to return a value.  You just print the number `n`; if it is bigger than 2, then call recursively with `n-2` and print `n` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I must be assuming something everyone else isn't. Either that or they just like obtuse code.

```
void func(int n)
{
    if (n > 2)
    {
        printf("%d ", n);
        f(n-2);
    }
    printf("%d ", n);
}
```

should be all that is required. Live example below

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int n)
{
    if (n > 2)
    {
        printf("%d ", n);
        f(n-2);
    }
    printf("%d ", n);
}

int main()
{
    for (int i=0; i<=10; ++i)
    {
        f(i);
        fputc('\n', stdout);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
0 
1 
2 
3 1 3 
4 2 4 
5 3 1 3 5 
6 4 2 4 6 
7 5 3 1 3 5 7 
8 6 4 2 4 6 8 
9 7 5 3 1 3 5 7 9 
10 8 6 4 2 4 6 8 10
```

Comment: You must be assuming that this is possible *without* using global / static variables.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog it's a world gone mad.

Comment: Nit: OP requested `"7 5 3 1 3 5 7"` not `"7 5 3 1 3 5 7 "` with that extra space after 7.  Good to leave something for OP to code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach (where the step is also configurable). It goes down towards ***1***, printing the numbers and calling itself (also printing the value smaller than step (the one in the middle, if any) **once** - the `else` branch), then when coming back (on the stack) from recursion, it prints the numbers again (the 2<sup>nd</sup> `printf`) in reversed order.

The program continues until user enters an invalid (including non positive *int*) value for ***n***.

*code.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define STEP 2


void func(int n, unsigned int step) {
    if (n > step) {
        printf("%d    ", n);
        func(n - step, step);
        printf("%d    ", n);
    } else if (n >= 1) {
        printf("%d    ", n);
    }
}


int main() {
    int n = 0;
    while (1) {
        printf("\n\nEnter n (invalid, to exit): ");
        if ((!scanf("%d", &n)) || (n <= 0)) {
            break;
        }
        printf("\nResults for %d (with a step of: %d):\n", n, STEP);
        func(n, STEP);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

> ```
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q052302083>test.exe
>
>
> Enter n (invalid, to exit): 6
>
> Results for 6 (with a step of: 2):
> 6    4    2    4    6
>
> Enter n (invalid, to exit): 7
>
> Results for 7 (with a step of: 2):
> 7    5    3    1    3    5    7
>
> Enter n (invalid, to exit): 8
>
> Results for 8 (with a step of: 2):
> 8    6    4    2    4    6    8
>
> Enter n (invalid, to exit): 9
>
> Results for 9 (with a step of: 2):
> 9    7    5    3    1    3    5    7    9
>
> Enter n (invalid, to exit): 3
>
> Results for 3 (with a step of: 2):
> 3    1    3
>
> Enter n (invalid, to exit): 2
>
> Results for 2 (with a step of: 2):
> 2
>
> Enter n (invalid, to exit): 1
>
> Results for 1 (with a step of: 2):
> 1
>
> Enter n (invalid, to exit): q
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>


int a;
int forward = 0;

int main() { 
    printf("Give a:");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    func(a);
    return 0; 
}

int func(int n)

{ 
    printf("\t%d \n",n);
    if (forward != 1 ) {
        if (n==1 || n==2)
        {
            //start printing from 1 or 2 to N
            forward = 1;
            func(n+2);
        } else {
            return func(n-2); 
        }
    } else {
       if(n >= a) {
            return;
        }
        return func(n+2);
    }
}
```

Comment: using global variables to control recursion isn't the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

Using static variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int n);

int main()
{
  int a;

  printf("Give a:");    
  scanf("%d", &a);  
  func(a);
  return 0;
}

void func(int n)
{
  static char reverse;
  static char init = 1;
  static int  val;

  if (init)
  {
      val = n;
      init = 0;
  }

  printf("%d\t",n);    

  if (n <=2 ) {
    reverse = 1;
  }   

  n += (reverse) ? 2 : -2;

  if (n > val) return;

  func(n);
}
```

Output:

```
7       5       3       1       3       5       7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution . I'm sure there's better ones but still ...

```
void rec(int n) {
    if (n%2==1 &&n==1) { printf("\t1"); return; }
    else if(n%2==0 && n==2)
    {
        printf("\t2");return;
    }
    printf("\t%d",n);
    rec(n-2);
    printf("\t%d",n);
}
int main()
{
    rec(7);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it was helpful !

Answer (score 0):

I would have a counter of some sort that you switch "on" when you are going upward. Pass in the counter as well as the original number into func().

I'm not sure of exact syntax, as I'm new to C after working for a year in C++, but this is what I would do.

```
counter = 0;
int func(int n, int counter, int originalNum)
{
    printf("\t%d",n);

    if(counter == 0)
    {
        if (n==1 || n==2)
        {
            counter = 1;
            return func(n+2, counter, originalNum);
        }
        return func(n-2, counter ,originalNum);
    }
    else
    {

        if (n == originalNum)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return func(n+2, counter, originalNum);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For fun, I thought I would try to improve on [@WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52302438/2410359) good answer and code a single function to not only print the sequence, but also output the spacing and sentinels as requested,   also no trailing space after last number.

```
7, then calling the function would print <<7 5 3 1 3 5 7>> ...
8, it would print <<8 6 4 2 4 6 8>>
```

The trick to this is that the function needs to know if it is the first call (to print the `"<<%d"`, `">>"` or a re-entrant one.  Since OP did not specify behavior for negative values, `func()` below uses the sign to indicate first or re-entrant call.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int n) {
  if (n > 0) {
    printf("<<%d", n);
    if (n > 2) {
      func(-(n - 2));
      printf(" %d", n);
    }
    printf(">>\n");
  } else {
    n = -n;
    printf(" %d", n);
    if (n > 2) {
      func(-(n - 2));
      printf(" %d", n);
    }
  }
}

int main(void) {
  for (int a = 1; a<= 10; a++) {
    func(a);
  }
}
```

Output

```
<<1>>
<<2>>
<<3 1 3>>
<<4 2 4>>
<<5 3 1 3 5>>
<<6 4 2 4 6>>
<<7 5 3 1 3 5 7>>
<<8 6 4 2 4 6 8>>
<<9 7 5 3 1 3 5 7 9>>
<<10 8 6 4 2 4 6 8 10>>
```

---

On a personal note, the code may benefit with some improvements, yet the code as posted is exactly what I typed and compiled the first time.  I have never written this many lines of code for a complete program that worked exactly as wanted with no edits: a [red letter day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_letter_day).